# How to destroy or delete a tkinter canvas packed into another canvas?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, destroy

I would like a clean and efficient solution to delete/destroy embedded Canvas objects. When I say "embedded Canvas objects" I mean a canvas which has been packed into another canvas.

My current solution is to go through and manually delete("all") .destroy() each canvas individually. This solution is extremely bulky, difficult to sequence, maintain, and leaves me worried that I'm not garbage collecting everything appropriately.

Experimenting with the code below shows me that nothing short of deleting the object itself (del (var)) will actually cause print(var) to produce an error. otherwise after var.delete("all") and var.destroy() print(var) produces .!canvas

```
from tkinter import *

# some arbitrary arrangement of canvas objects

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1600x900")

# highest level
topLevel = Canvas(root, bg="blue")
topLevel.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# second level
redTop = Canvas(topLevel, bg="red")
redTop.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

greenBottom = Canvas(topLevel, bg="green")
greenBottom.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

# third level
blackBox = Canvas(redTop, bg="black")
blackBox.pack(side=LEFT)

whiteBox = Canvas(greenBottom, bg="white")
whiteBox.pack(side=RIGHT)

mainloop()

# possible cleanup methods
def my_current_solution():
    # starting with the leaf nodes and traversing back in order
    blackBox.delete("all")
    blackBox.destroy()
    del blackBox

    redTop.delete("all")
    redTop.destroy()
    del redTop

    whiteBox.delete("all")
    whiteBox.destroy()
    del whiteBox

    greenBottom.delete("all")
    greenBottom.destroy()
    del greenBottom

    topLevel.delete("all")
    topLevel.destroy()
    del topLevel


def same_but_automated(list):
    # assume list is made up of canvases inserted in proper order
    for canvas in list:
        canvas.delete("all")
        canvas.destroy()
        del canvas


def what_I_hope_is_okay():
    # eliminating only the root *hopefully* does not cause a serious memory leak?
    topLevel.delete("all")
    topLevel.destroy()
    del topLevel
```

No error messages, just want to know if I'm clogging up my code or the memory unnecessarily. Looking for a cleaner, simpler, more efficient solution.

Comment: to embed any widget in canvas you have to use `widget_id = canvas.create_window(pos, widget)`, not `pack/grid/place`. The same is  with canvas embeded in canvas.

Comment: So would this method cause canvas.delete("all") to catch the widget_id?